# Spring boot skipping and duplicating items in pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Users endpoint to get all the users in MySQL sorted by a boolean value using pagination, as the number keeps growing I found out it's **skipping some users** and **duplicating others** here's some screenshots in postman where a user with the same id (**95**) is duplicating in 2 different pages

Also sometimes i can't find some users in all the pages

## Page 2

[image: Text]

## Page 3

[image: Text]

## ServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public PagedResponse<?> findAll(UserPrincipal currentUser, int page, int size) {
        AppUtils.validatePageNumberAndSize(page, size);
//return users with 'isBoard' true first
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, "isBoard");
        if (currentUser.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN.toString()))
                || currentUser.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(RoleName.ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN.toString()))) {
            Page<MEUser> contentPage = userRepository.findAll(pageable);
            List<MEUser> list = contentPage.getNumberOfElements() == 0 ? Collections.emptyList() : contentPage.getContent();
            return new PagedResponse<>(list.stream()
                    .map(user -> mapToAllUsersDTO(user, new AllUserDTO()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()), contentPage.getNumber(), contentPage.getSize(), contentPage.getTotalElements(), contentPage.getTotalPages(), contentPage.isLast());
        } else {
            Page<MEUser> contentPage = userRepository.findByMemberTrue(pageable);
            List<MEUser> list = contentPage.getNumberOfElements() == 0 ? Collections.emptyList() : contentPage.getContent();
            return new PagedResponse<>(list.stream()
                    .map(user -> mapToAllUsersDTO(user, new AllUserDTO()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()), contentPage.getNumber(), contentPage.getSize(), contentPage.getTotalElements(), contentPage.getTotalPages(), contentPage.isLast());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a second sort column to guarantee a consistent ordering? Try using the if column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a database problem rather than in your code. The database does not ensure consistent results when there's multiple rows with the same value of an ordered field.

When using pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` you have to supply an order by field with unique values, so in your case you have to sort by `isBoard` and `id` to ensure consistent result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the if condition is validating only ADMIN and SUPER_USER. user 95 may have other roles that come in else conditions. Please check once and provide the database info for Roles and Users.

Comment: the problem is happening with admin role

Answer (score 0):

i added the id condition to the pagination:

```
Pageable pageable = 
  PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("isBoard").descending().and(Sort.by("id")));
```